# ошибка в плагине sass

Tags: html, css, gulp, sass

не подскажите что не так? и как исправить?

так же при установке npm install -g gulp ошибка 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: кавычки поставьте в пути до файла. Т.е. `@import "sass\vars"`

Comment: в файле  gulpfile.js?

Comment: _На первом скрине не ошибка_, а рекомендация обновить пакет minimatch до версии 3.0.2 или выше во избежание Regexp DoS. А также, как можно скорее обновить пакет graceful-fs до версии 4.0.0 или выше.  
    
_На втором - ошибка_: в первой строке файла sass/vars.sass в директиве __@import *bourbon ;__  <--- не хватает закрывающей двойной кавычки перед точкой с запятой..